# inserting outlook appointment using c#, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, outlook

Im looking to insert an appointment in a users calendar,
I can easliy insert in my own using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application (below),
then add the user as a recipient, but what if I dont want to add myself, if I only want to add others? Can this be done in a similar way?

thanks

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null; 
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem appt = null; 
            app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application(); 

            appt = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem); 
            appt.Subject = "Meeting "; 
            appt.Body = "Test"; 
            appt.Location = "a room"; 
            appt.Start = Convert.ToDateTime("08/08/2012 05:00:00 PM"); 
            appt.Recipients.Add("a@b.com"); 
            appt.End = Convert.ToDateTime("08/08/2012 6:00:00 PM"); 
            appt.ReminderSet = true; 
            appt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15; 
            appt.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh; 
            appt.BusyStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy; 
            appt.Save();
```

Comment: Have you tried this in outlook? I believe you are an attendee automatically when you create an appointment. You won't have an option in outlook to remove your name. If outlook doesn't allow, Interop won't have any option for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot (or should not) use the Outlook API from an ASP.NET application. Instead Exchange Server provides a [Web Services SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd877012%28v=exchg.140%29) that allows you to interact with the Exchange Server. The documentation has a sample of how [to create appointments in a user's mailbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa563060%28v=exchg.140%29).

You may have to delegate access to the user account used to execute the ASP.NET request to succesfully be able to interact with the Exchange Server API.

EWS was first introduced in Exchange 2007. For older versions of Exchange you can use Collaboration Data Objects (CDO). The Exchange 2003 SDK contains documentation on how to [create appointments and meeting requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/ms870494%28v=exchg.65%29).

Comment: Hi, should have pointed out, we're running Exchange 2003 at the moment, cant seem to find a web services dll for 2003, is there such a thing??